# Relationship b/t Matrix Probability and Rank

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the set X of all 2 × 2 matrices with matrix entries 1 or
>   2. The probability of a set of matrices Y with some property is the
>   number of matrices in Y divided by the number of matrices in X. What is the probability that the rank of the matrix is 0? 1? 2?

So, there are 16 total possible 2x2 matrices. The rank of a matrix is the # of leading 1s-- so, for the first question, would this be (1)/(16)? There is only 1 possible matrices with leading 1s (all 1s)?

Comment: That's not the definition of rank. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It is the number of leading 1s in rref, no?

Comment: That's a method to compute the rank, but that's not the definition. The definition is that the rank is the maximal number of linearly independent rows (or columns, the two concepts turn out to be the same). In the problem at hand, the method is not useful but the definition is.